# Ant: how to write optional nested elements

Tags: ant, macrodef

Say that I need to do something like:

```
<copy todir="${DEPLOYMENT_DIR}" overwrite="true">
    <fileset dir="dir1" />
    <fileset dir="dir2" />
    <fileset dir="dir3" />
    ...
    <if>
        <equals arg1="${SPECIAL_BUILD}" arg2="true"/>
        <then>
            <fileset dir="dir7" />
            <fileset dir="dir8" />
            ...
        </then>
    </if>
</copy>
```

(The real task is not copy, I'm just using it to illustrate the point.)

Ant will complain that my task doesn't support nested `<if>` which is fair enough. I've been thinking along these lines:

I could add a macrodef with an "element" attribute like this:

```
<macrodef name="myCopy">
    <element name="additional-path" />
    <sequential>
        <copy todir="${DEPLOYMENT_DIR}" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir="dir1" />
            <fileset dir="dir2" />
            <fileset dir="dir3" />
            ...

            <additional-path/>
        </copy>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

But that would mean that the caller (target) must specify the additional path which I want to avoid (if many targets call this task, they would have to repeat the fileset definitions in the `additional-path` element).

How to code the additional filesets *inside* the macrodef so that Ant doesn't complain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (not sure if a good one) to achieve that is to create two macrodefs - one "public" for general use and one "internal" that does the real work and is intended to be called only from the "public" macro. Like this:

```
<macrodef name="task-for-public-use">
    <sequential>
        <if>
            <equal arg1="${SPECIAL_BUILD}" arg2="true" />
            <then>
                <internal-task>
                    <additional-path>
                        ...
                    </additional-path>
                </internal-task>
            </then>
            <else>
                <internal-task ... />
            </else>
        </if>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>


<macrodef name="internal-task">
    <element name="additional-path" />
    <sequential>
        <copy ...>
            ...
            <additional-path/>
        </copy>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

I don't like it much though and hope there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

**AntContrib** has an Ant [**FileSet** object augmented with *if* and *unless* conditions](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/fileset.html).

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/fileset.html

> **if** Sets the property name for the 'if' condition. The fileset will be
>   ignored unless the property is
>   defined. The value of the property is
>   insignificant, but values that would
>   imply misinterpretation ("false",
>   "no") will throw an exception when
>   evaluated.
>
> **unless**    Set the property name for the 'unless' condition. If named
>   property is set, the fileset will be
>   ignored. The value of the property is
>   insignificant, but values that would
>   imply misinterpretation ("false",
>   "no") of the behavior will throw an
>   exception when evaluated.

You could use it like this:

```
<copy todir="${DEPLOYMENT_DIR}" overwrite="true">
    <fileset dir="dir1" />
    <fileset dir="dir2" />
    <fileset dir="dir3" />
    ...
    <fileset dir="dir7" if="SPECIAL_BUILD" />
    <fileset dir="dir8" if="SPECIAL_BUILD" />

</copy>
```

Comment: That's nice but the copy+fileset was chosen just as an example. In my case the "copy" is "mxmlc" (Flex application compiler) and "fileset" is "include-libraries". Still upvoting as the contrib FileSet seems useful.

Comment: @Borek - another approach that I have taken is to invoke an XSLT stylesheet to build a costom ANT build.xml, then invoke that custom-generated build.xml file from within the main build.xml's target. If you update the question with something more in line with what you are trying to do, I could post an example.

Comment: I'd rather stay with "pure Ant" which is messy enough :) I've posted my current solution - not the most elegant one but achieves the task.

Comment: That's cool. It's probably the most appropriate for your needs. FYI - `<if>` is not "pure Ant", it's also an ant-contrib extension that is more procedural than declarative Ant style.