# Get value held in Ant element

Tags: java, ant, macrodef

Let's say I have a macrodef like so

```
<macrodef name="Test">
    <element name="someName"/>
    <sequential>
        <java classname="path_to_Test">
            <classpath> blah </classpath>
            <arg value="someText and {valueOfsomeName}"/>
        </java>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Then further down I have a target which uses this macrodef, like

```
<target name="testMacrodef">
    <Test>
        <someName value="someValue"/>
    </Test>
</target>
```

My question is, how do I get `{valueOfsomeName}` to be exactly the string `someValue`? I can't seem to get it to work at all.

Also, just for a bit of context, I can't just use an attribute tag instead of an element tag, as I need it to be an *optional* argument.

I've Googled for ages trying to find a solution for this; maybe there isn't one. But as far as I can see no one has asked this, and it doesn't seem to be covered well in the Ant documentation either, so if it's not possible is there a way of having an optional attribute?

EDIT: spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple [echo](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) if element has only text content, f.e. :

```
<macrodef name="Test">
 <element name="someName" optional="yes"/>
 <attribute name="foo" default="bar"/>
  <sequential>
   <echo>
    <someName/>
   </echo>
   <echo> @@{foo} => @{foo}</echo>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>

<Test>
 <someName>blablabla..</someName>
</Test>
```

output :

```
[echo]     
[echo]    blablabla..
[echo]  @{foo} => bar
```

otherwise for nested xml content use [echoxml](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoxml.html), f.e. :

```
<macrodef name="Test">
 <element name="someName" optional="yes"/>
 <attribute name="foo" default="bar"/>
  <sequential>
   <echoxml>
    <someName/>
   </echoxml>
   <echo> @@{foo} => @{foo}</echo>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>

<Test>
 <someName>
  <echo>blablabla..</echo>
 </someName>
</Test>
```

output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<echo>blablabla..</echo>
[echo]  @{foo} => bar
```

If you need the element values for further processing use echo / echoxml to file and [loadfile](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) afterwards.
**--EDIT after comment --**
Echo to file :

```
<macrodef name="Test">
 <element name="someName" optional="yes"/>
 <attribute name="foo" default="bar"/>
  <sequential>
   <echo file="somefile.txt">
    <someName/>
   </echo>
   <echo> @@{foo} => @{foo}</echo>
  </sequential>
```

or

```
<macrodef name="Test">
 <element name="someName" optional="yes"/>
 <attribute name="foo" default="bar"/>
  <sequential>
   <echoxml file="somefile.txt">
    <someName/>
   </echoxml>
   <echo> @@{foo} => @{foo}</echo>
  </sequential>
```

and use loadfile afterwards => creates property (= string) with content.
When using echoxml strip of the xml header with filterchain :

```
<loadfile srcfile=" ... " property="whatever">
 <filterchain>
  <headfilter lines="10" skip="1"/>
 </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

Adapt the value of headfilter lines attribute to your needs.
Property whatever will have the value :

```
<echo>blablabla..</echo>
```

Comment: I tried this previously, but then how would I include those contents in a string? For example, I want to do the equivalent of `<arg value="text "+<someName/> />` where `"text "+<someName/>` is the equivalent of setting  `<arg value="text someNameContents"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I always do something like this:

```
<macrodef name="test">
    <attribute name="foo"/>
    <sequential>
        <echo message="@{foo}"></echo>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="so">
    <test foo="Hello SO." />
</target>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I mentioned, I can't use an attribute tag because I need it to be optional. If I use an attribute tag, it's required, and the file won't build unless I specify a value for it. You might think I could just assign a default value of "", but unfortunately that messes with the parsing of arguments on the Java side of things. I don't want to have to cater for the ant script in the Java code, so using attributes (unless there's something special I'm missing) is out of the question.

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986937/ant-how-to-write-optional-nested-elements